# Xcode9 WARNING ITEMS-90704, ERROR ITMS-90022

Tags: xcode9, application-loader

```
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not 
contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' 
pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
```

---

```
WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 
1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the 
Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review."
```

I set the appropriate image (PNG format) in all fields of the xcassets file.

But one error and warning comes out.

Environment

- Xcode 9.0 release version
- Cocoapods
- Carthage

Comment: i solved it:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885406/4305700

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 9 has new icon sizes. Please check the Images.xcassets file: AppIcon

Comment: Dont know why the down-vote! This was the solution, simply by adding an image to the xcasset (as you mentioned, new size appear in the bottom)... Thx

Comment: thank you this helped me. I am now adding new required icon hopefuly it wont ask anything else

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In my case, it indicates a missing of AppStore Icon;
Xcode9 added a new icon in AppIcon called App Store iOS 1024pt, so add the icon missing resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the 90704 message said, "iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog **or via iTunes Connect**, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review." This indicates that having the store icon as part of the store listing as I've always had it is enough. But Apple wouldn't accept my app until I also added the store icon to the app itself (in the AppIcon asset catalog).

My app has a watch extension, and I also had to add the store icon to the watch extension's asset catalog.

Don't forget to increment your build number after adding the icons, or Apple will then reject the app for having a duplicate build number.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a bug of APFS/Xcode 9/CocoaPods...
You can archive your application by Xcode 9 and upload this archive by Xcode 8. Or you can edit Info.plist file in the archive and switch the value of field 'BuildMachineOSBuild' to 16A323. Why this? I don't know, but it works. I found this solution here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290
After uploading you see only warning.

**UPD**:
Probably Apple fixed this bug. Now my archives are uploaded correctly without any modifications.

Comment: Here is the command to change the BuildMachineOSBuild; 

find Products/ -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 16A323

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue when tried to submit the app from macOS 10.13 High Sierra.

Everything was okay when we switched to stable macOS 10.12.6